# Is there a way to capture dump of an ASP.NET Core process only when an exception with a particular signature occurs

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm trying to diagnose a request failure scenario caused by a possible concurrent access to `HttpContext`. The thing is that the issue is reproducible only on a server and that too when put under load.

A simple dotnet-dump collect output will not help because that only gives the state of process at a particular point in time. What I'm trying to find out is if a dump can be triggered when a particular condition is met. The intent is to collect detailed stack trace at the point of the exception.

For example, take dump when a null ref exception is thrown when a particular property on a particular type is accessed.

As of now, I've tried to make the app code as lean as possible. Got rid of unnecessary middleware in request pipeline. But the stack trace I see I get of exception is hardly of any use.

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: All the `dump collecting` tool requires to tigger manually for instance, `procmon`, `dibug diag`, so have you tired with any diagnostic features like telemetry?

Comment: @davidfowl OS is RHEL.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron I'm looking for something similar to debugdiag, but for Linux. If I'm not wrong, on Windows, debugdiag can attach itself to process as a debugger and capture dumps at specified conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Well, based on your comment, It seems you are looking for tool like `debug-diag` for `linux` machine. You could consider [`ProcDump for linux version`](https://github.com/Sysinternals/ProcDump-for-Linux) which similar to debug-diag tool but for linux as no other suitable tool available. However, it has few fature limitaions. Please follow the below insturctions if that meet your requirement.

**Installation guideline:**

1. Please [`check here for details instruction`](https://github.com/Sysinternals/ProcDump-for-Linux/blob/master/INSTALL.md#install-procdump)

**Minimum Requirements:**

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Minimum OS:

Red Hat Enterprise Linux / CentOS 7

Fedora 29

**Note:**

Please note that, Curreent version does not have full feature parity with Windows version of ProcDump, specifically, stay alive functionality, and custom performance counters.

For more details, you could visit our [`official document`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procdump#related-links) as well.